# ¿Cómo calcular el promedio de una lista de datos?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin

Hola reyes de la sabiduría, en este caso me topo con un problemita que me tiene con dolor de cabeza buscando hacerlo de la mejor manera...

Para mostrarles lo que me urge mejor les pongo un ejemplo: Tengo una tabla A que tiene el la siguiente información

```
----------------------
|  NOMBRE  | CANTIDAD |
----------------------
|  PERRO   |   10     |
----------------------
|  GATO    |    5     |
------------------------
```

Ahora, a esta tabla quiero `add` una nueva columna que indique el promedio que representa cada animal (en este caso) que el resultado sería algo como:

```
|  NOMBRE  | CANTIDAD | PROMEDIO |
----------------------------------
|  PERRO   |   10     |  66.66 % |
-----------------------------------
|  GATO    |    5     |  33.33 % |
----------------------------------
```

El problema es que para sacar esa tabla "A" tuviera que crear muchas tablas auxiliares y el sql es bastante grande... No quisiera extenderme más de lo que ya estoy; por eso quisiera saber la mejor forma de hacerlo o la que mejor ustedes crean.

Cualquier respuesta en bienvenia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, agrega al menos el código para la creación de tablas por favor

Answer (score 1):

Segun tu ejemplo lo que requieres es el %(por ciento) y no el promedio, pues el promedio de 10 y 5 es 7.5 y ahí pones 66.6 y 33.3 , ahora basado en que es el por ciento te comento:

1- agrega una columna vacía a la tabla.

2- luego le haces un update con el calculo respectivo al %.

asegúrate que no haya nadie accediendo a los datos de dicha tabla pues puede provocar bloqueos y comportamientos no deseados.

en tu caso:

```
CREATE TABLE a (nombre text, cantidad int);

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('perro', 10),('gato',5);

--agregas la columna
ALTER TABLE a add column porciento numeric;
--haces el update con el calculo respectivo
UPDATE a set porciento = round( (cantidad*100)/(select sum(cantidad) from a),2 );

SELECT * FROM a;


 nombre | cantidad | porciento 
 --------+----------+-----------
 perro  |       10 |     66.00
 gato   |        5 |     33.00
(2 filas)
```